# Is $\mathscr F(\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N))=\mathrm{Hom}_{S\text{-mod}}(\mathscr F(M),\mathscr F(N))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, definition

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings.

Let $\mathscr F$ is a functor from $R$-mod to $S$-mod.

Let $M,N$ be two $R$-modules. Then $\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N)$ is an $R$-module and $\mathrm{Hom}_{S\text{-mod}}(\mathscr F(M), \mathscr F (N))$ is an $S$-module.

Since $\mathscr F: R\text{-mod} \to S\text{-mod}$ is a functor, then this defines a function
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{S\text{-mod}}(\mathscr F(M),\mathscr F(N)).$$

However, since $\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N)$ is itself an $R$-module, **do we know what the object $\mathscr F(\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N))$ must be, based on $\mathscr F$?**

**Must it be the $S$-module $\mathrm{Hom}_{S\text{-mod}}(\mathscr F(M),\mathscr F(N))$?**

Comment: How about the functor that sends all $R$-modules to the $0$ $S$-module?

Comment: @RghtHndSd That would make both objects be zero.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, they are not the same in general.

Let $S = ℤ$ and $\mathscr F$ be the forgetful functor $R\mathrm{-Mod} → \mathrm{Ab}$. Then $\operatorname{Hom}_S (\mathscr F M, \mathscr F N)$ is the set of abelian group homomorphisms $M → N$ and $\mathscr F \operatorname{Hom}_R (M, N)$ is the abelian group of $R$-module homomorphisms $M → N$. Clearly, they are not the same in general, as not every abelian group homomorphism $M → N$ has to respect the $R$-structure of the modules. Take $M = N = ℂ$ as $ℂ$-modules, for example.

The counterexample of course generalises to other scalar restrictions.

Then, in general, the concept you are looking for are functors of [closed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_category). These are functors of closed categories that respect the internal hom-functor. The category of $R$- or $S$-modules is not only a closed category, but a [cartesian closed category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category).

So we have seen that not every functor $R\mathrm{-Mod} → S\mathrm{-Mod}$ respects the internal hom-functor, but there are functors that do. Boring examples include the null functor and the identity for $R = S$. If I find a nonboring example, I’ll let you know.

---

In general, there may be *some* connection. Taking again the scalar restriction example from above, we have for instance at least a natural inclusion map $$\mathscr F \operatorname{Hom}_R (M, N) → \operatorname{Hom}_S (\mathscr F M, \mathscr F N),$$
which just happens to almost never be an isomorphism. But at least it’s a natural inclusion.

A similar phenomenon occurs for $R = S$ when $R$ is an integral domain and $\mathscr F = T$ is taking torsion modules. For $R$-modules $M$, $N$, we have a map
$$T \operatorname{Hom}_R (M,N) → \operatorname{Hom}_S (TM, TN),~f ↦ f|_{TM → TN}$$
but it doesn’t even have to be injective now, for example if $M$ happens to be nontrivial torsion-free and $N$ happens to be a nontrivial torsion module, with $M$ mapping nontrivially into $N$ somehow. So, $M = ℤ$ and $N = ℤ/nℤ$ over $R = ℤ$ for example.

If I can think of a nonboring example with a natural map going in the other direction, I’ll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another kind of example: take $R = S$ and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the functor sending $M \mapsto M^{\oplus 2}$. Then $$ \mathscr F(\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N)) \simeq (\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N))^{\oplus 2}
 $$ while $$ \mathrm{Hom}_{S\text{-mod}}(\mathscr F(M),\mathscr F(N)) \simeq (\mathrm{Hom}_{R\text{-mod}}(M,N))^{\oplus 4}$$ so they would not be the same in general.